# How to avoid API requests shown when call npx cypress open?

Tags: cypress, coded-ui-tests

I'm writing tests using Cypress for the UI of an application that has polling - it makes API requests every 2 seconds.
I would like to run the tests in the `--headed` mode (by `npx cypress open`) and to see in the list only the steps that I wrote for the UI, and not the requests which happen a lot and are polluting the list of the steps.

I haven't found any command in the Cypress documentation for that so far, would appreciate any help!

Comment: In case someone wants to expand this into a full-fledged answer, here's a solution: https://gist.github.com/simenbrekken/3d2248f9e50c1143bf9dbe02e67f5399 (which is basically the same as the link-only solution posted by the question asker).